# Nginx running and enabled but not serving

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

I currently have lighttpd web server working on my main website, and I want to change it to nginx.

So I decided to run the nginx on another port to configure it with my website and see if it works.

I configured ngixn on port 81, using this:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/sub.domain.net.conf

```
server {
        listen 81;
        server_name localhost;

        root /var/www/html/dev.mydomain.net/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        #charset koi8-r;
        # access_log /var/log/nginx/example1.com/example1_access_log;
        # error_log   /var/log/nginx/example1.com/example1_error_log   error;

       location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

       # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {

                root    /var/www/html/dev.mydomain.net/;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9072;  #set port for php-fpm to listen on
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        }
}
```

- Nothing in my nginx error log.
- Trying to access Port 81 from the browser loads long time then shows "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

I tried: `netstat -tulpen | grep 81`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9142881    28807/lighttpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9477801    30676/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      27         9081177    28139/mysqld
```

Any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -tulpen | grep 81`?

Comment: you have double root which is unessecary

Comment: @digijay added the output

Answer (score 0):

Found it! 
Opening the port is necessary, without it nothing will work. This information is missing in many web tutorials.

I used this:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=81/tcp
success
[root@centos7 ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
success
```